# How to prevent duplicate request in react-native onTextChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';
import _ from 'lodash';
import api from '../utils/api';
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const toast = str => {
  Toast.show(str);
};

export default class InputSearch extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keyword: '',
    listData: [],
    currentPage: 1,
    refreshing: false,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // this.fetchSearchData = _.debounce(this.fetchSearchData, 500);
  };

  handleOnChangeText = async text => {
    this.setState(
      {
        keyword: text,
        listData: [], // I cleared listData
      },
      this.fetchSearchData,
    );
  };

  fetchSearchData = async () => {
    const {keyword} = this.state;
    try {
      const data = await api('/upload/video', {query: {keyword}});
      const {listData} = data;

      console.log('listData should be [] but is not', this.state.listData);

      this.setState({
        listData: this.state.listData.concat(listData),
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('saul fetchSearchDataError', err);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height,
          backgroundColor: '#eee',
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{width: 375, padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
          autoFocus={true}
          selectionColor={'#333'}
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.handleOnChangeText(text);
          }}
          value={this.state.keyword}
        />
        <FlatList
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => {
            return null;
          }}
          ListFooterComponent={() => {
            return null;
          }}
          horizontal={false}
          data={this.state.listData}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={() => {}}
          onRefresh={() => {}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  renderItem = ({item, index, separators}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        <Image
          style={{width: 375 / 2, height: 100}}
          source={{uri: item.imageUrl}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

As I set listData to blank, every time I changed Text in TxtInput and to fetch data from server my state listData should be empty.Right ?

but I get duplicate views in my UI. Why ?

I guess when I changed my text in TextInput, multiple request was send to server at the same time which make state update randomly and can not be sure listData is empty when I call this.setState(). If I am right, how  to prevent this happen ?

Comment: No time to analyse your code deeply, but consider two things: first of all is never a good practice making a request on every textInput change, instead use the debounce function from lodash you've already imported; secondly, I think your setState callback in `handleOnChangeText` is not properly formatted, try `this.setState({...}, () => this.fetchSearchData())`

Comment: I did all you suggested. Still get duplicate data back.